Connect to MongoDB Atlas using Delphi Firedac Driver?
I am struggling to connect to a MongoDB Atlas database using the Firedac component. I have the MongoDB Atlas connection string but am unsure how to
setup the connection in Delphi. I note that the Data API has been recently deprecated in MongoDB so a REST connection is not a viable option.
Grateful for any advice from anyone who has successfully created a connection.
